# "Save as csv" not available

Tags: csv, gnumeric

How can I save single spreadsheet as a csv file in Gnumeric (version 1.12.28)?

Going through *File - Save As* offers several file types like .gnumeric, .xls or .ods, but **not** .csv.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to follow this way to open a "Save As" dialog where you can choose other file types (csv is among them):

*Data - Export Data - Export as CSV File...*

Comment: Wow, that's really unintuitive. Since `gnumeric` can also save in ODS formart in the "Save as"-dialogue, I would expect that CSV is also there ...